# Problem in grasping wavelength of light

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, waves, wavelength

I am having a problem grasping the concept of wavelength of light. We define wavelength as the minimum distance between two particles of a wave vibrating in the same phase , but in case of light there is nothing physically vibrating , so what exactly is the wavelength of light? If we define light as the oscillation of electric and magnetic field lines then why don't we see alternate patches of dark and bright light , as in some places their collective magnitude is zero while at some it's high due to variation of phase .
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The electric and magnetic fields are vibrating. (And traveling so there's really no "dark" patches.)  You can fairly easily set up experiments where interference  effects create light and dark nodes, although they are not nodes on the wavelength scale in the experiments in high school.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the maxima and minima in amplitude (Electric field) is half the wavelength. For visible light this will be of the order of 200-300 nm. Definitely you won;t see this by eye.
But a different problem is that for a traveling wave the pattern changes in time. Where you had a minimum a little later is a maximum. This alterantion happens about 10^14 times in each second. For eye, everything than changes faster than about 100-1000 time per second cannot be resolved (so we can have films and TV).
But in a standing wave the pattern is stationary and could be "seen" if the wavelength is long enough for the detector used.

Answer (score 1):

> We define wavelength ...

The wavelength, $\lambda$, of a single frequency,$f$, wave is the distance which a fixed-value phase point travels in a single period, $T=1/f$. The phase of a wave can be expressed as $$\frac{2\pi}{T}t-kx+\phi_0,$$
where $k$ is called the wave number and $\phi_0$ is the phase of the wave at $t=0,x=0.$
If we examine the phase at ($t=t_1,\ x=x_1$) and say that phase point has travelled to $x_2$ when $t=t_1+T$, we say that $x_2-x_1$ defines the wavelength:
 $$\frac{2\pi}{T}t_1-kx_1+\phi_0=\frac{2\pi}{T}(t_1+T)-kx_2+\phi_0$$
 $$-kx_1=2\pi-kx_2$$
 $$x_2-x_1=\frac{2\pi}{k}=\lambda.$$
So, the wave number must, by definition be $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$.

I believe the phase point travel per period provides a better definition of wavelength than finding a distance between similar vibrations. It also works conceptually for EM waves.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the idea of particles moving comes from assuming that the wave  propagates on a material medium, moreover, what the wave $u(t,{\bf x})$ models is the displacement of the medium at time $t$ and location ${\bf x}$ w.r.t its equilibrium position $u=0$. This last notion actually allows you to extend the interpretation to light waves: $u(t,{\bf x})$ models how much the electromagnetic field departs from $u=0$. With this in mind, you can then define wavelength as the minimum distance between two position at which the field $u$ have the same phase.

As for the second question, you are right: if you could make an experiment in which a *single coherent* electromagnetic wave (a single wavelength $\lambda_0$) was generated in front of you, you could probably experience how the amplitude would go to zero as you move to the source, going back up, and to zero again after $\lambda_0$. The problem is that building such an experiment turns out to be very difficult, if not impossible. Even the most sophisticated lasers have some spread around $\lambda_0$ (bandwidth).

In less constrained environments, it is actually impossible to see it. This is because all light you see, comes from different directions, generated by all kind of sources, with different phases, frequencies and amplitudes!

Comment: Re, "...you could probably experience how the amplitude would..." No, because you can not see light.  You can see _things_ because the photons that things emit or reflect trigger chemical reactions in the retinas of your eyes when they are absorbed there.  But even if you had some perfectly coherent light trapped in an optical resonator on a bench in front of you, you would not be able to see the crests and troughs of the standing wave.   Not even in principle.   And, you would not be able to see its photons bouncing back and forth between the mirrors.